# VScode Type hints (Python-Pylance)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, type-hinting, pylance

Help solve the problem with the type hints.
When I want to override a class parameter or method I get a suggestion from IntelliSense(Pylance)
When I choose a hint (because it suits me) editor itself adds a type hint.
I went through all the settings and can't find a solution to the problem.

Example:
`typing show_change_link after hint choice i get show_change_link: bool`

I'm not interested in these autocomplete functions or autocomplete parameter types.

When languageServer Jedi everything works fine and does not add this unnecessary nonsense.

Comment: https://imgur.com/fyrxPli

Comment: https://imgur.com/Zcy5kos

Comment: Added additional images so u can see my problem

Comment: Your images do not add any clarity to the situation.  Are you saying you want no type hinting?

Comment: @TimRoberts Yes my man. This hints added automaticly. In second photo i did not write anything. VsCode(Pylance) fill the method by itself without my participation.

Comment: @TimRoberts https://imgur.com/a/ERwOxlJ

Comment: In the Pylance settings, does `Inlay Hints: Variable Types` help?

Comment: @TimRoberts as you can see on  the video this type hint added by itself, with no need. So i must type all by my hands or chose intelli hint and delete garbage that i did not need

Comment: @TimRoberts this parameter disabled in settings. So this does not solve my problem((

Answer (score 1):

This is a new feature added in the [July update of Python extensions](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/python/python-in-visual-studio-code-july-2022-release/#inlay-type-hints). You can add the following codes to your **settings.json** to close it:

```
“python.analysis.inlayHints.functionReturnTypes”: false,
“python.analysis.inlayHints.variableTypes”: false,
```

Comment: Hi friend. Like I said, this is done by pylance itself when selecting a hint. The parameters you specified are already disabled in the settings. The problem occurs when reassigning parameters or class methods. The only solution which helped so far is switching to Jedi LanguageServer. But your suggest may be useful for someone else:)

Comment: Why i see problem in this. Cause it did not work like hint. It exactly adds the type-hint to the code. Not like visual helper.

Comment: This is strange. Even in the [August update](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/python/python-in-visual-studio-code-august-2022-release/#double-click-to-accept-type-hints), you still need to double click to add it to the code. Have you updated your Pylance?

Comment: Of course my man. All extensions up to date