# VSCode generate python function/class with inputs and outputs datatype

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I hope to let the vscode automatically generate the function or class template with the datatypes. Something like,

if I type a function like

```
def add(a, b):
   t = a + b
   return t
```

And then the VSCode can automatically help me complete the template like

```
def add(a:$, b:$) -> $:
    return a + b
```

And then I can type a datatype into `$` and use `tab` to jump to the next `$`. I have seen this feature in PyCharm. I think it should also be available in VSCode.

Comment: your best bet is probably GitHub Copilot or another tool powered by AI, you need something that can predict what you're thinking since there's a lot of ambiguity without you explicitly putting the types, especially in Python (even in this example, where `a` could be anything that has a `__add__` function that doesn't throw and `b` could be anything `a.__add__` accepts

Comment: I don't need it predicts the input is a `int` or `str`. I only want to get a template, and I can type the datatype manually.

Comment: are you saying that you want `def $($: $, $: $) -> $:` where each $ is a place to input the name of the function, each argument and type, and the return type?

Comment: We don't do recommendations on Stack Overflow (see [on-topic](/help/on-topic) number 3), plus it's not clear what you want. What input would you give the extension in order for it to generate this code? Maybe something like "A function that adds two integers"?

Comment: Yes. I was thinking every time when I type a `def some_fun(a, b)`, the VSCode can automatically help me change to `def some_fun(a:$, b:$)->$:`.

Comment: OK, so then what you're asking is for it to automatically add the syntax for type annotations, then you'll fill in the types.

Comment: What's this feature called in PyCharm? If you search for "VSCode" + [feature name], that should help.

Comment: I fail to see how having go back to the beginning of the parameter list and pressing tabs any faster to type than simply typing a colon and a space after each parameter. Hardly worth writing an extension for.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VScode Type hints (Python-Pylance)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74229061/vscode-type-hints-python-pylance)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### The following two methods are for your reference:

1. Turn on the following settings and embed prompts will be displayed on the line of code

   ```
       "python.analysis.inlayHints.functionReturnTypes": true,
       "python.analysis.inlayHints.variableTypes": true,
   ```

   [image]

   If you specify types for `a` and `b`, you can double-click to insert the following prompts

   [image]
2. You can customize code block prompts, and you can read [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_create-your-own-snippets) for details.

   Here is a simple example I wrote

   **python.json**

   ```
   {
       "def": {
           "prefix": "def",
           "body": [
               "def ${1:func_name}(a: ${2:type}, b: ${3:type}):",
               "\tt = a + b",
               "\treturn t"
           ],
           "description": "def"
       }
   }
   ```

   [image]